# Корректно ли предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

«В 1995 году был принят на службу в органы внутренних дел в МВШ МВД России» - корректно ли так писать?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю. что такое МВШ, но словосочетание "органы внутренних дел" рядом с  МВД - лишнее.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь, Вероника, существует сразу два ответа.Если Вы придерживаетесь обычного, разговорного, стиля речи, то этот вариант является верным. Но если Вы бы придерживались делового стиля речи, то это предложение было бы неправильным.

Answer (score 0):

По всей вероятности, МВШ - это какая-то (Например, Московская) высшая школа. Тут явно перебор с "внутренними делами". Можно посоветовать такой вариант: "«В 1995 году был принят в МВШ МВД России»